# Marketing Cloud AMPScript - Condition to check if a prospect is or is not in SF

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I need to be able to check if a prospect is or is not in SF to unsubscribe him from my AllSubscribers tab.

I'm checking if the prospect is a contact, a lead, or an account in SF ; and if yes, I'm making the needed changes. The issue is that I also need to be able to able to make the changes, even if the prospect is not in SF. And I cannot manage to do that with conditions, if the differents SET for SF are not respected, I'm getting a 500 error, so I don't know how to proceed anymore.

Can someone help me please?
Basically, I need to be able to unsubscribe 4 types of prospects : only in Marketing Cloud / Contact in SF / Lead in SF / Account in SF

Thanks!

Here is a part of my code:

```
VAR @skey, @email
SET @skey = AttributeValue("_subscriberkey")
SET @email = AttributeValue("emailaddr")

SET @Subscriber = CreateObject("Subscriber")
SetObjectProperty(@Subscriber, "SubscriberKey", @skey)
SetObjectProperty(@Subscriber, "EmailAddress", @email)
SetObjectProperty(@Subscriber, "Status", "Unsubscribed" )
SET @Status = InvokeUpdate(@Subscriber)
 
VAR @contact_rows, @lead_rows, @account_rows
SET @contact_rows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects(
   "Contact", 
   "HasOptedOutOfEmail", 
   "Id", "=", @skey)
SET @lead_rows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects(
   "Lead", 
   "HasOptedOutOfEmail", 
   "Id", "=", @skey)
SET @account_rows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects(
    "Account", 
    "PersonHasOptedOutOfEmail", 
    "Id", "=", @skey)

 IF RowCount(@contact_rows) == 1 THEN 
   VAR @contact_row, @optedout_contact
   SET @contact_row = Row(@contact_rows, 1)
   SET @optedout_contact = Field(@contact_row, "HasOptedOutOfEmail")
   IF @optedout_contact == false THEN
    VAR @result_contact
    SET @result_contact = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject("Contact", @skey , "HasOptedOutOfEmail", "true")
   ENDIF
  ENDIF 

  IF RowCount(@lead_rows) == 1 THEN 
   VAR @lead_row, @optedout_lead
   SET @lead_row = Row(@lead_rows, 1)
   SET @optedout_lead = Field(@lead_row, "HasOptedOutOfEmail")
   IF @optedout_lead == false THEN
    VAR @result_lead
    SET @result_lead = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject("Lead", @skey, "HasOptedOutOfEmail", "true")
   ENDIF
  ENDIF

  IF RowCount(@account_rows) == 1 THEN 
   VAR @account_row, @optedout_account
   SET @account_row = Row(@account_rows, 1)
   SET @optedout_account = Field(@account_row, "PersonHasOptedOutOfEmail")
   IF @optedout_account == false THEN
    VAR @result_account
    SET @result_account = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject("Account", @skey , "PersonHasOptedOutOfEmail", "true")
   ENDIF
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

1. Check if the person is in SF, if yes, unsubscribe them from there
2. On top of that, always unsubscribe them from Marketing Cloud, regardless if they exist in SF or not

```
%%[
SET @skey = _subscriberkey
SET @jid = RequestParameter("jobid")
SET @listid = RequestParameter("listid")
SET @batchid = RequestParameter("batchid")
SET @reason = "One click unsubscribe"

/* check if any contacts, leads or accounts found for subscriber in SF */

SET @contact_rows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects(
   "Contact", 
   "HasOptedOutOfEmail", 
   "Id", "=", @skey)
SET @lead_rows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects(
   "Lead", 
   "HasOptedOutOfEmail", 
   "Id", "=", @skey)
SET @account_rows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects(
    "Account", 
    "PersonHasOptedOutOfEmail", 
    "Id", "=", @skey)

/* if yes, unsubscribe them in SF */

 IF RowCount(@contact_rows) == 1 THEN 
   VAR @contact_row, @optedout_contact
   SET @contact_row = Row(@contact_rows, 1)
   SET @optedout_contact = Field(@contact_row, "HasOptedOutOfEmail")
   IF @optedout_contact == false THEN
    VAR @result_contact
    SET @result_contact = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject("Contact", @skey , "HasOptedOutOfEmail", "true")
   ENDIF
  ENDIF 

  IF RowCount(@lead_rows) == 1 THEN 
   VAR @lead_row, @optedout_lead
   SET @lead_row = Row(@lead_rows, 1)
   SET @optedout_lead = Field(@lead_row, "HasOptedOutOfEmail")
   IF @optedout_lead == false THEN
    VAR @result_lead
    SET @result_lead = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject("Lead", @skey, "HasOptedOutOfEmail", "true")
   ENDIF
  ENDIF

  IF RowCount(@account_rows) == 1 THEN 
   VAR @account_row, @optedout_account
   SET @account_row = Row(@account_rows, 1)
   SET @optedout_account = Field(@account_row, "PersonHasOptedOutOfEmail")
   IF @optedout_account == false THEN
    VAR @result_account
    SET @result_account = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject("Account", @skey , "PersonHasOptedOutOfEmail", "true")
   ENDIF
  ENDIF 

/* if no contacts, leads or accounts found, unsubscribe from SFMC only */

SET @lue = CreateObject("ExecuteRequest")
SetObjectProperty(@lue,"Name","LogUnsubEvent")

SET @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")                 
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "SubscriberKey")
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @skey)
AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)

SET @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "JobID")
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @jid)
AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)

SET @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "ListID")
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @listid)
AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)

SET @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "BatchID")
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @batchid)
AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)

SET @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "Reason")
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @reason)
AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)

SET @lue_statusCode = InvokeExecute(@lue, @overallStatus, @requestId)

SET @Response = Row(@lue_statusCode, 1)
SET @Status = Field(@Response,"StatusMessage")
SET @Error = Field(@Response,"ErrorCode")

]%%
```

Comment: Hello!

First, thanks for the answer!

The issue, is that I also need to unsubscribe them form Marketing Cloud, even when they are in SF.

Also, I'm having thoughts about this code because, how can I SET some parameters from Salesforce objects, when they might not exist? (meaning if the prospect is only in MC). When I tried on my own, I was having error with the SET.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I have edited my answer - now it will always unsubscribe from SFMC, and on top of that, if someone exists in SF, it will unsub them from there as well. Can you please clarify what you mean by "how can I SET some parameters from Salesforce objects, when they might not exist" - if they don't exist you cannot use them - but what paremeters are they and what for do you need them?

Comment: I will try yes, the issue is that when I'm testing with someone that is only in MC, the page is not loading and I'm getting an issue "{"message":"Call to retrieve records for salesforceobject Contact failed!", which is understandable because the prospect is not in SF. So that's why I need a condition or something, so that the page can load, even if the prospect is only in MC. Thanks!